# Message[Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes.] Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]

Tags: c#, google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client

We have an Issue when we are trying to update the google spread sheet with the google api.

**ERROR**

> Exception in processSheetPAGoogle.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>   Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes.
>
> [400] Errors [Message[Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes.] Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]]

Comment: when I am running multiple reports at a time I am having this problem.can any help me.

Comment: Few people suggested to go with premium Account but that doesn't helped me.

Comment: Isn't the error message pretty clear.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code. There is no real way to fix this issue with the sheets api other than to make your batch sizes smaller.   Premium account doesnt work with sheets it doesnt have a premium account.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal -Thank you for the reply and the above is the actual error I got while debugging.

Comment: @DaImTo-Thank you for the responce.I am able to update the spread sheet when record count is less like below 5000 but for the count like 15k or 20k it is throwing the above error.

Comment: Yes I know,  it's clearly explains what the error is. Max payload size limit is: 10485760 bytes, you are sending more data than that, but you can't do that.